# Prevent change of field if related objects exist?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-validation

I have two models in my Django application:

```py
class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SURVEY_TYPES)

class Response(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    response = models.TextField()
```

When the organizer of the survey has created the survey, they get to specify the type. Once the first response has appeared, I don't want the organizer to be able to change the type using the site admin (as the freetext response field in the Response model would change meaning).

I have looked into using validators, but as far as I can determine, they are intended to operate on forms, not on objects to be saved. I cannot find any support for performing database queries in them.

I have also looked into overriding the save method, but as far as I can determine on that end, is that it is not expected to be used for validation (and I would prefer not to put any logic whatsoever in my models).

The way I would have done this in other frameworks it so introduce some layer above the ORM that allows me to introduce business rules. Please advise - what is best practice here?

Comment: Just to clarify: It is important that the survey_type be on the Survey model, not in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use model-level validation:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SURVEY_TYPES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._old_survey_type = self.survey_type

    def clean(self):
        if (self.survey_type != self._old_survey_type) \
                and survey_typeself.response_set.exists():
            raise ValidationError('Cannot modify the type of a started survey')
```

Be careful though, `Model.clean` is not automatically called when you save an object. It does when when a `ModelForm` gets validated (hence also in admin), but otherwise you have to check if it does or call it yourself.

Comment: This isn't checking whether the survey type has changed, so it will always raise a validation error if a response exists. What if there was a second field on the `Survey` model that was allowed to be changed?

Comment: The comment from @Alasdair is accurate - this should only prevent the change of `survey_type` if there are responses. Is there any way to access currently stored field values and incoming field values?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to make this into some generic pattern where I can place business rules outside the model somehow. Need to think some more about it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

set `survey` and `response` field in `Response` model unique by
[unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) like this:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    response = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("survey", "response"),)
```